# Dynamically add the Matrix/GridView based on the values from the TextBox in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, gridview, tablelayoutpanel

I wanted to ask some questions regarding some requirements. My client want that when he clicks on a Button, a form should be displayed asking the user to add the number of rows and columns.After adding those a matirx/gridview should be displayed according to the size that the user has entered.
The main problem is that I have used a TableLayoutPanel and its not changing the size of the rows and columns.

```
     public void set(int rows, int columns)
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = rows;
        tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = columns;
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new ComboBox());
        //tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add( NewRackControl() rack());
        this.ResumeLayout();
        //this.Refresh();

    }
```

1. What will be best to add a GridView or a TableLayoutPanel?
2. How can I change the number of rows and columns.
3. Thirdly if a user enter text to any of the position of that gridview how I will be able to take the position of that paticular row or column and then save it into the Database ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `TableLayoutPanel` please use `DataGridView`

the Selected Rows from different popped form can be passed between 2 forms and update can be done to the working Grid-view.

- The changes required (like Sizes, Color, Icons ,Highlighting, etc)
  can be Done in Gridview.
- You can change the no of rows & columns dynamically by changing properties(visibility & items) of it.
- yes, you can save the changes made in view back to database and this is one of famus features provided by updateble event.

Please use **DataGridView** this is best for your Problem.

Comment: I have created a function which is taking the rows and columns but again its not showing me to the UI

 public void DGV_Creation(int columns, int rows)
        {
            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add("col" + i, "column " + i);
                dataGridView1.Columns[i - 1].FillWeight = 1;
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            }
        }

Comment: Use this code:
dataGridview1.Columns.Add(Total_col_Count);
dataGridview1.Columns[0].ColumneName="SomeText";
Same way for all columns... add there names.,

To change the columns input/Control type use this
dataGridview1.Columns[0].ColumnType="DataGridViewComboBoxColumn";

Comment: It is not allowing me to pass the single parameter into it. Now how I have to do that?? Really confused

Comment: Please help me out I do not know how to do it. I want to add the empty gridview of X rows and Y columns and each column will have a button so that if a user clicks on that button I can get the position of that particular row and col..

Comment: You can access the cells based on its row and column index, in same way you can alter its values also..

Access Values:  string x=datagridview.rows[0].cells[1].value;
Set its Values: datagridview.rows[0].cells[1].value="aaa";
Change its Properties:
dataGridView[4, 0].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;

Comment: To Get the position of the cell clicked, please follow the click event.
Click_Event(Sender.. ,e.. )
{
  e.RowIndex;  /// X value 
  e.ColumnIndex; //// Y Value..
}

Comment: But first I have to show the empty grid according to the user entered row and column. Getting the position is the next step. Its not showing me the grid even.

Comment: It takes the col and row size but not displaying it into the UI? It there any function through which I can display the gridview rows and columns?

Comment: It will not display any row or column unless until you programmatic create columns and add rows. 
For demo purpose you create new application and create datagridview and change in its properties to add columns in it and see .. its easy.